High school movie/series; students with bats fighting monsters?
All the details are really fuzzy to me, it's been years since I watched the movie/series? So bad I can't even remember if it was a movie or series. I apologize in advance for being all over the show. I really can't remember.
It takes place in high school; students and people from outside of school hide in classrooms away from monsters/aliens.  There is an older man who has a gun and threatens people who try to open the doors. Men from the army appear and the students think they are now safe but something goes wrong. One of the students gets infected and his mother has a cure (well at least I think she does) and he has to leave the school He gets taken in an ambulance/military van?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Scouts Guide to the Zombie Apocalypse (2015) maybe? It's zombies though.

Three scouts, on the eve of their last camp-out, discover the true meaning of friendship when they attempt to save their town from a zombie outbreak.




